# Inno setup - how to change version in the setup hover?

Tags: version, inno-setup

I am able to set application version in the Inno script and that appears correctly in the control panel. But when I hover over the setup file itself, I am not getting the right version. It simply shows as 0.0.0.0. What is the difference?

[image]

How to change the version in the hover display? What do you think I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `VersionInfoVersion` directive in your `[Setup]` section:

```
[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{93A88F3C-324F-4BAF-B14C-85E44C59742E}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
VersionInfoVersion=1.0.0.0
```